# Contacts from phone in own application

Tags: android

How can I implement contacts in my own app? I want to, when I click on button, show all contacts from my phone. Can you tell me something about it? Like in when you want send SMS. Click on button, choose contacts and send.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you query the full contacts and add into list view and select contact, then you search of query contacts.

```
 Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

             phones.moveToFirst();
               for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
               {
                  String lookupKey =  phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to `starActivityforResult` with below intent

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)`;

define a constant like int `PICK_CONTACT = 1;`

```
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

and should have onActivityResult method such as below.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact name.
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

here is complete tutorial for this [how-to-call-android-contacts-list](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/how-to-call-android-contacts-list.html)